# Does Gazebo 11 go with both ROS Melodic and Neotic?

Tags: gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Just to clarify, is it true that Gazebo 11 will be possible to be used with both ROS melodic (Ubuntu Bionic) and ROS Neotic (I assume Ubuntu Focal)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24720/does-gazebo-11-go-with-both-ros-melodic-and-neotic?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2020-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, that's the plan. Gazebo 11 will be the official version for Noetic and Foxy, and it will also be supported with Melodic.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1315/ruffsl/) on 2020-04-16**:
Is there a github ticket we can follow for release of ros_gazebo_pkgs for Foxy?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-04-16**:
None yet, feel free to ticket one.